# Margintop in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, margin

Hello Is het possible to set a margintop for a form element in actionscript?

var frm:Form = new Form();
frm.setStyle("marginTop", 20);

Or something like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.  You need to set `paddingTop`, instead of `marginTop`.

So:

```
var frm:Form = new Form();
frm.setStyle('paddingTop', 20);
```

Comment: i want the textfields in the form pushed a little down (or how do you say that), I think I need margin right? i don''t want the whole form to go down.

Comment: sounds to me like paddingTop is exactly what you want then.